# How can I clean a bundle file with npm?

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

How can I delete the contents of a file (`bundle.js`) with an npm script so that after running `npm run clean` the `bundle.js` would be just an empty `.js` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### bash

If you only intend to support `bash` environments then define a script named `clean` in `package.json` as shown below:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "clean": "echo > path/to/bundle.js"
},
...
```

The above simply `echo`'s an empty string to the file using *bash's* [echo](https://ss64.com/bash/echo.html) command.

---

#### Windows

If you only intend to support `Windows` environments, (i.e. running via *cmd.exe* or *Powershell for example)*, then change the `npm-script` as follows:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "clean": "echo: > path/to/bundle.js"
},
...
```

Again, this time we also `echo` an empty string to the file, however this time we use *windows's/cmd* [echo](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) command.

Note the intentional colon (`:`) after `echo`

---

#### Cross-platform

Unfortunately the *bash* solution will not run on *Windows* and vice versa (...this is because of the different `echo` syntax required).

If you require a solution to work cross-platform, which I guess you probably do, then consider writing a custom *node.js* utility script and invoking it via `npm-scripts`.

The following shows how this can be achieved:

**clean.js**

```js
var fs = require('fs');

if (process.argv.indexOf('-p') !== -1) {
  var filePath = process.argv[process.argv.indexOf('-p') + 1];
  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, '');
}
```

`clean.js` can be saved to a hidden folder named `.scripts` in your projects root directory and configured in the `scripts` section of `package.json` as follows:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "clean": "node .scripts/clean -p path/to/bundle.js"
},
...
```

---

#### Additional Notes

1. In all three example `npm-script` gists above the path which reads `path/to/bundle.js` will need to be redefined a necessary.
2. To clear the contents of `bundle.js` run the following via your CLI:

`$ npm run clean`

Answer (score 0):

The npm packages **rimraf** and **touch** are both available for command-line usage in `scripts`.

First install locally into your project:

```
$ npm install --save-dev rimraf touch
```

Then add the `clean` script to your **package.json** file:

```json
"scripts": {
   "clean": "rimraf dist/bundle.js && nodetouch dist/bundle.js",
}
```

To use the script:

```
$ npm run clean
```

The **rimraf** command (named after `rm -rf`) deletes the file.
See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf#cli

The **nodetouch** command (which is the cli part of **touch**) creates the empty file.
See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/touch#cli

The `&&` operator effectively runs both commands (technically, it's doing a boolean **AND** which means the second command will not execute if the first command fails).